# Vsftpd with sqlite3 as PAM

Tags: vsftpd, debian-wheezy, sqlite

**Long Version**
I have a vsftpd server setup on my Raspberry Pi (running "Raspbian GNU/Linux 7" a flavour of Debian Wheezy). I would like to setup accounts using PAM. If possible I would use sqlite3 since it is only small and it wouldn't fill up the storage on my Raspberry Pi unlike MySql. I have found a [PAM library for sqlite3 on github](https://github.com/sangeeths/libpam-sqlite) but I have no idea on how set it up to work with my vsftpd server.
I heard of using a command that comes with Apache called htpasswd but I don't have Apache installed since I use Apache Tomcat 7 in my home directory and it does not seem to include htpasswd. 
 
**Short Version**
How can I get users on my vsftpd server without using over 50 MB or creating users loggable into SSH?

- Daniel

Comment: search for virtual users, depending how many you want you might not need a DB for that. example
  http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by installing Apache2 but disabling it by doing the command:
`sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable`
That I found in the second answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/32438/disable-a-service-from-starting-at-all-runlevels) and you can read more about that command in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/how-to-stop-a-daemon-from-starting-up-on-boot-up-in-debian). So that Apache 2 doesn't start up automatically since I use Apache Tomcat 7.
Then I followed the tutorial found [here](http://www.sigerr.org/linux/setup-vsftpd-custom-multiple-directories-users-accounts-ubuntu-step-by-step/) on setting up virtual users using htpasswd.
Also since I wanted to use SSL I added the following lines to the `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
# SSL
ssl_enable=YES
# this selects the cipher type
ssl_ciphers=HIGH

# choose according to your preference
force_local_data_ssl=YES

# choose according to your preference
force_local_logins_ssl=YES

# enable this if you enable ssl.
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES

# give the correct path to your currently generated *.pem file
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=12000
pasv_max_port=12100

# Some mobile clients require this
require_ssl_reuse=NO
```

Just replace `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem` in the line `rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem` with the path to your ssl certificate. I can't remember the link I used to generate my ssl certificate but I think I used a command similar to the one found [in this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-vsftpd-tls-on-debian-squeeze).